# slicing column name from every head row in excel sheet and looping though sheet name's in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, slice

I am trying to insert data from a excel file which contains multiple sheets with every sheet name a corresponding table exist in database. Now what I thought as a approach was loop on sheet Name and create a recursive SQL in a loop that goes for all the sheet Names. Now in the loop suppose first sheet name come then there are few checks that check for if table exist in database or not and verify the column name from the sheet as well the column name from database. if everything's is good then it will insert the sheet data into the database.

Challenges which I am facing are:

1 - Get the Sheetname from pandas

```
        xls = pd.ExcelFile<filepath>
        Sheet_name = x.sheet_names

I am not able to loop through it although it contains all the sheet name but for() is not working.
Help me with a iteration code.
```

2 - Help me with slicing column name from the head row of every sheet to confirm the column name.

```
I am placing a few piece of code that i have been working on, help me with syntax error's as well

Their are errors in SQL code as well Please help me with them also
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
Import the oracle lib

Create -----> DB_Connection 
mycursor = DB_Connection.cursor()
xls = pd.ExcelFile('File Path')
SheetNames = xls.sheet_names

for i in SheetNames:
    SelectSql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM all_tab_columns where OWNER = 'XYZZZ' and TABLE_NAME = '"i"' "
    mycursor.execute(SelectSql)
    QueryResult = mycursor.fethcone()

if(pd.isnull(QueryResult)):
    Print("Table doesn't exist in database")
else:
    """    Add the Data frame slicing code to get Column name's to Check if same Exist in Database or Not    """
    
    GetColumnSql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '"i"' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION"
    mycursor.execute(GetColumnSql)
    ColumnName = mycursor.fetchall()
    
    InsertSql = "INSERT INTO '"i"'('"ColumnName"') VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
    VAL0 = """  insert from dataframe  """
    mycursor.execute(InsertSql,VAL0)
    
    DB_Connection.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1)

The `sheet_name` parameter of the `read_excel` function can be `None`. When doing that, the return value will not be a pandas DataFrame, but a dictionary. Its keys will be the sheet names and the values the DataFrames themselves.

You can then iterate through that dictionary and do your check.